# The rendering library could not be initialized in Android

Tags: android, xml, rendering

[image: The error is shown in the image at the right bottom]

I installed ANDROID Studio in my PC. I installed everything including the SDK. But yet I am getting this error. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

As the log says, try to refresh the layout, if this doesn’t work try to restart Android Studio.

Comment: com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.RenderingException: The rendering library could not be initialized
 at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibraryLoader.loadImpl(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:89)
 at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:115)
 at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:182)

Comment: at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:174)
 at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$RenderTaskBuilder.lambda$build$0(RenderService.java:581)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: I can only suggest to reinstall Android Studio, I have no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

go to File->Settings->Experimental->Editor-> and uncheck the Use new Layout Rendering Engine then hit OK and restart Android Studio. Hope this solution helps someone.