# The rendering library could not be initialized

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

After lots of time invested in android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1, android design and blueprint are not showing the design layout. Anyone is here who can help or suggest the best solution.

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion also shift from any version 32 to 21.

[image]

Comment: What is Android design and blueprint? Could you add screenshots of not working features?

Comment: @CoolMind i have attached the screenshot

Comment: Strange, but I have similar version (2021.1.1 patch 2), and haven't had such error for a long time. What is shown in Details?

Comment: I tried to find experimental settings (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777623/the-rendering-library-could-not-be-initialized-in-android), but they don't have rendering properties. You can try to change experimental settings (Ctrl + Alt + S, select last item `Experimental` in left tree, then probably change quality settings).

Comment: @CoolMind getting issue in mac, may be issue because of mac os

Comment: Maybe so. What if try to download and install some build from Canary channel (it there are any releases)?

Comment: @CoolMind yes I have tried with the Canary channel update, but still getting the issues.

Comment: in Mac os, File->Settings->Experimental->Editor-> and uncheck the Use new Layout Rendering Engine this option is not available. please share the screenshot if you find the above steps.

Comment: Excuse me for a bad advice. I have these options (didn't change): https://pastenow.ru/ffb282bffd6fab1a8dee79e2e9b8497c.

Comment: @CoolMind I have same the same also, but still design blueprint does not show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242568/discussion-between-coolmind-and-imran-khan).